# Select statement, but table is a subquery?

Tags: sql, database, subquery

I separate my users by roles, so the basic **users** table has very little information, the rest is in separated tables where role specific information is stored.

So I want to do a SELECT statement in SQL but the table Im selecting has to be the value of a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM (subquery);
```

In this case the subquery is the value from the users role in the users table, so i know where to look for the rest of the information.

```
SELECT role FROM users WHERE email = 'jhondoe@example.com';
```

All together:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT role FROM users WHERE email = 'jhondoe@example.com');
```

(Theoretically) This would transalte to this:

```
SELECT * FROM students;
SELECT * FROM parents;
SELECT * FROM teachers;
```

Depending on the email;

Comment: I think you'll need another subquery to group all of the users one table.

Comment: Not wure why it has to be the value of a subquery rather than a join. But to get your sql in the question working you will need to alias the subquery - put `as students` for example at the end after the closing bracket. But show your schema and sample data and expected result to get a proper solution

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL.  That is usually a sign that the data model could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate your query into a variable and then execute it with the EXEC function:

```
declare @query nvarchar(MAX);
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + (SELECT role FROM users WHERE email = 'jhondoe@example.com');
EXEC(@query)
```

Or if all your tables have the same structure, you could merge them together and select the records that match the correct role:

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT *, 'students' as PersonRole FROM students
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'parents' as PersonRole FROM parents
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'teachers' as PersonRole FROM teachers)

as tMerged

WHERE PersonRole IN (SELECT role FROM users WHERE email = 'jhondoe@example.com')
```